# Passing multiple values to ABAP TEXT FILTER with VBA

Tags: vba, saprfc

I've created a macro to read data from SAP Table using the BAPI `BBP_RFC_READ_TABLE`.

It successfully compiles and runs for a single parameter if I use the FILTER VIEW:

```
objOptTab(objOptTab.RowCount, "TEXT") = "EBELN EQ '12345'"
```

However, the goal of the code is to be able to pass an array of strings as the textfilter, therefore the `ekknPurchaseOrders` variable exists. As SAP uses SQL Queries and share a lot of syntax with general SQL language, I would assume I could pass below as a TEXT FILTER:

```
ekknPurchaseOrders = "('12345', '67890', '101112')"
```

This is why the below line is there in the first place:

```
"EBELN IN " & ekknPurchaseOrders'
```

Running the code/executing BAPI with `EBELN IN "`.. results in an SQL_PARSE error, because the syntax is invalid.

Any suggestions as to what syntax I may utilize to pass a collection of multiple values to the EBELN TEXT FILTER?

Take note that the TEXT FILTER syntax is changed from 'EQ' to 'IN' when the error occurs. Passing multiple values using `ekknPurchaseOrders` and *not* changing syntax to 'IN' returns the value for the first element in `ekknPurchaseOrders`.

```
    Public Const worksheetName As String = "EKKN"
    
    Public Sub GetEKPOtable()
    
        Dim funcs As SAPFunctions
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetName)       
             
        
        'LOG IN TO SAP
        Set sapConn = CreateSapFunctions()
        If sapConn Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        'DECLEARE FUNCTION EXPORTS
        Set objRfcFunc = sapConn.Add("BBP_RFC_READ_TABLE")
        Set objQueryTab = objRfcFunc.Exports("QUERY_TABLE")
        Set objDelimiter = objRfcFunc.Exports("DELIMITER")
        Set objRowCount = objRfcFunc.Exports("ROWCOUNT")
        
        'SET VALUES
        objRowCount.Value = "99999999"
        
        Set objOptTab = objRfcFunc.Tables("OPTIONS")
        Set objFldTab = objRfcFunc.Tables("FIELDS")
        Set objDatTab = objRfcFunc.Tables("DATA")
        
        objQueryTab.Value = "EKPO"  'TABLE
        objDelimiter.Value = "|"    'DELIMITER
        objOptTab.FreeTable
        
        'OPTION FIELD SAP STATEMENT
        objOptTab.AppendRow
        objOptTab(objOptTab.RowCount, "TEXT") = "EBELN IN " & ekknPurchaseOrders 'FILTERS FOR VIEW
        objFldTab.FreeTable
    
    
        'OUTPUT FIELDS
        objFldTab.AppendRow
        objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "EBELN"
        objFldTab.AppendRow
        objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "EBELP"
        objFldTab.AppendRow
        objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "EMATN"
        objFldTab.AppendRow
        objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "ELIKZ"
    
    
        'IF CALL FAILES, EXIT
        If objRfcFunc.Call = False Then
            MsgBox objRfcFunc.Exception
        End If
        
        Dim objDatRec As Object
        Dim objFldRec As Object
        
        
        'WRITE RESULT TO WS
        Dim lo As ListObject
        Set lo = ws.ListObjects(outputTable)
        
        Call ClearTableData(lo)
        
        For Each objDatRec In objDatTab.Rows
            For Each objFldRec In objFldTab.Rows
                ws.Cells(objDatRec.Index + 8, objFldRec.Index + 7) = Mid(objDatRec("WA"), objFldRec("OFFSET") + 1, objFldRec("LENGTH"))
            Next
        Next
    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Running the code/executing BAPI with EBELN IN ".. results in an SQL_PARSE error, because the syntax is invalid.

[`WHERE IN`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenwhere_logexp_list.htm) syntax perfectly works in RFC_READ_TABLE and BBP_RFC_READ_TABLE, your problem lies elsewhere.

Three moments to pay attention when troubleshooting your code:

1. `OPTIONS` parameter has 72char limitation for single line which you probably hit. Check your condition length and split it into several lines if needed.
2. `OPTIONS` lines do not "like" lack of spaces so do not spare the characters

instead of line

```
objOptTab(objOptTab.RowCount, "TEXT") = "EBELN IN ('050112','060201')
```

push this

```
objOptTab(objOptTab.RowCount, "TEXT") = " EBELN IN ( '050112', '060201' )
```

3. And don't forget to escape values in your `ekknPurchaseOrders`, every value [should be enclosed in single quotes](https://saplsmw.com/node/101)!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the post. I did not know that the OPTIONS parameter has a 72char limitation. This will amputate the project, as the parameters passed usually are between 50 and 200 characters. Are you familiar with any way to increase this length? Or can I append a new row with a new set of OPTIONS?

Comment: Your answer answers the question at hand, thus I'm accepting. It does not completely solve my problem , due to the OPTION character limit. If I do figure out a workaround in the future, I'll post it here.

Comment: `Or can I append a new row with a new set of OPTIONS?` of course. That what I was trying to tell you  in in 1st pt. suggesting to split. Your `objOptTab` is a table that can have multiple lines